# Deleting duplicates from a table using mulitple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to delete records from a table by finding duplicates under two columns.

I have manage to identify the records using the following;

```
SELECT SiteName, Postcode 
FROM [Active Site Locations]
GROUP BY SiteName, Postcode
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

However when I try to run a DELETE to remove them from the table I get the following.

```
DELETE FROM [Active Site Locations] 
WHERE (Select SiteName, Postcode, count(*) FROM [Active Site Locations]
GROUP BY SiteName, Postcode
HAVING count(*) >1 );
```

You have a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's from clause. Revise the select statement of the subquery to request only one field.

I do however need to check both columns SiteName and Postcode and if the match then I need to remove them, can somebody help please.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  The syntax suggests MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses a correlated subquery to count the number of matches and then uses `> 1` in the outer query for the comparison:

```
DELETE FROM [Active Site Locations]
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM [Active Site Locations] as asl          
       WHERE asl.SiteName = [Active Site Locations].SIteName AND
             asl.Postcode = [Active Site Locations].Postcode
      ) > 1;
```

Comment: ok, so ran the query but now it deletes a lot more records than shown in the select statement, how can that be running the select statement I get a total 1188 records that are duplicates but when I run either of the solutions it deletes 2472 records which is well over the 1188 that I expected it to remove.

Comment: @user2244590 . . . As described in your question, this deletes all versions of duplicate records.  Perhaps you actually intend to keep one of the records?  If so, you can ask another question.  Perhaps I totally misunderstand the intention, but this question seems geared toward removing all copies of duplicate records.